# Array being converted to dict json data

Tags: php, json

Im trying to create a multidimensional associative array but when i json encode the array it shows it as a Dict instead of an array. Could it be the way i use the keys 
$this->jsonArray['Friends'][$status] = $friend;

```
<?php

// Connection to Database
include('connection.php');

// Username Submitted
$username = $_POST['signinusername'];

// Password Submitted
$password = $_POST['signinpassword'];

// Creates new instance of Login Class
$user = new Login($username, $password, $db);



/**
 * Login Class
 *
 * This class takes the username and password posted and checks whether they match
 * a username and password in the database if they do two other functions are called
 * that get both the friends of that user and the groups they are in. All data is encoded in json
 *
 * @copyright  2014 Phil and Matt Technologies
 * @license    http://www.php.net/license/3_01.txt   PHP License 3.0
 * @version    Release: @package_version@
 * @link       http://grouporder.site90.net/signin.php
 * @since      Class available since Version 1.0
 */ 

class Login
{

  private $connection;
  private $id;
  private $username;
  private $password;
  private $status;
  private $idArray = array();
  private $nameArray = array();
  private $jsonArray = array('Friends' => array(),'Groups' => array()); 

  /**
 * Function Constructor
 *
 * @param Name $username Stores the submitted username in a private variable.
 * @param Password $password Stores the submitted password in a private variable.
 * @param Object $db Creates new mysqli connection to database and stores it in a private variable.
 */ 

  function __construct($username, $password, $db)
  {
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->result_array;
    $this->connection = $db;
    $this->authenticate();

  }

 /**
 * Checks if username and password are correct
 *
 * 
 * @return Status
 *
 */ 

  private function authenticate()
  {

    $query = "SELECT idUser,Password FROM Users 
              WHERE Username = ?
              LIMIT 1 ";

    if($stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query))
    {

      $stmt->bind_param('s', $this->username);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      $stmt->bind_result($this->id,$hash);
      $stmt->fetch();

      // compare the password to the expected hash
      if (password_verify($this->password, $hash))
      {
        $this->status = 'Sucess';
        $this->getFriends();
        $this->Groups();

      }

      else
      {
        $this->status = 'Failed';      
      }

    }

    $stmt->close();

    $this->jsonArray['Status'] = $this->status;


  }

 /**
 * Checks database for friends of logged in user.
 *
 * 
 * @return Friends List
 *
 */ 


  private function getFriends()
  {

    $query = "SELECT Username, Status 
              FROM Users 
              INNER JOIN Friends 
              ON Users.idUser = Friends.idFriend 
              WHERE Status = 'Accepted' AND Friends.idUser = ? ";

        // Prepares and excutes the query
        if($stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query))
        {

            $stmt->bind_param('s', $this->id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($friend, $status); 

            for ($i=0; $stmt->fetch(); $i++) 
            { 
               $this->jsonArray['Friends'][$status] = $friend;
            } 

        }


  }

 /**
 * Checks database for groups and members of that group of logged in user.
 *
 * 
 * @return Group List
 *
 */ 

  private function Groups()
  {

    // Mysql query that gets all group names in the database that the user is a member of
    $groupName = "SELECT GroupName, Groups.idGroup  
                  FROM Groups
                  INNER JOIN Members
                  ON Groups.idGroup = Members.idGroup
                  WHERE Members.idMember = ? ";

    // Mysql query that gets all members in each group that the user is a member of
    $groupMembers = "SELECT Users.Username, Users.idUser
                     FROM Members
                     INNER JOIN Users
                     ON Members.idMember = Users.idUser
                     WHERE idGroup = ? ";

    // Prepares and excutes the query                 
    if($stmt = $this->connection->prepare($groupName))
    {

      $stmt->bind_param('s', $this->id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($groupName, $idGroup);
      $stmt->store_result();
      $groupNum = $stmt->num_rows;

      while ($stmt->fetch()) 
      {

        $this->idArray[] = $idGroup;
        $this->nameArray[] = $groupName;

      }

    }

    $stmt->close();

    // For loop that checks the database for members part of users groups and appends them to array grouplist

      for ($i=0; $i < $groupNum; $i++) 
      { 

        // Helper Variable that holds each helperArray element
        $idVariable = $this->idArray[$i];
        $nameVariable = $this->nameArray[$i];

        $this->jsonArray['Groups'][$nameVariable]['GroupID'] = $idVariable;

        // Prepares and excutes the query
        if($stmt = $this->connection->prepare($groupMembers))
        {
          $stmt->bind_param('s', $idVariable);
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->bind_result($username, $userid);

          for ($j = 0; $stmt->fetch(); $j++) 
          {

          // Adds user to list of users of that group
          $this->jsonArray['Groups'][$nameVariable]['GroupMembers'][$userid] = $username;

          }

        }

      }

  }

   /**
   * Function Destructor
   *
   */ 

   public function __destruct()
    {
      echo json_encode($this->jsonArray);
    }

}



?>
```

Json Output

```
{"Friends":{"Accepted":"test2"},"Groups":{"Group1":{"GroupID":1,"GroupMembers":     
{"1":"test"}}},"Status":"Sucess"}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: when i use a json viewer it says that its a dict type instead of an array like it should. I need it to be an array because i am putting this data into an iPhone app

Comment: Can we see your Objective C code for deserializing the JSON please.

Comment: Im not the one deserializing the code someone else is. Im doing the php portion i know nothing about objective c they said that I need to change it from dict to an array

Comment: I ask because that's usually a problem when people aren't JSON Decoding the returned data.

Comment: the problem is somewhere in the php code because in visual json it shows it as a dict and i thought i declared it as an array